# Pillow-based basic GUI library for an LCD

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, gui, raspberry-pi

I am working with an LCD screen and an RPi. The library I use sends 1-bit images to the screen, so I wrote this library based on Pillow to help developing the on-screen GUI.  I am playing with the thought to release this on the appropriate forums.

I would really appreciate some feedback, and this is one of the only places where I can get any. Apart from that, I am also curious if the approach I took is good, and what should I do before actually releasing the code.

**About the code:**

I made it running without the two device-specific modules. Normally it would work as in the `main()` function. I tried to be as documented and readable as I could, and I also included some error handling.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  untitled.py
#  
#  Copyright 2016 Gergely Nagy <passznemtudom@gmail.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#
__author__ = "Gergely Nagy"
__license__ = "GPL"
__version__ = "0.1b"
__status__ = "development"



import time
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageChops

debugging = True

if not debugging or __name__!='__main__':
    # These device-specific modules are only neccessary if using a real Nokia 5110
    #   LCD screen, for debug usage (LcdCanvas.target is None) they can be left out
    import PCD8544 as LCD
    import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI


# Nokia LCD screen dimensions
LCD_WIDTH = 84
LCD_HEIGHT = 48




class LcdCanvas(object):
    """
    A GUI for the Nokia 5110 LCD screen. It features two kind of cards: image cards and textboxes.
    Cards are moveable images on the base image (normally a blank white/black one). Textboxes are a
    special type of cards: they show the given text, and their image is generated automatically.
    Cards are referenced by their (unique) ID.

    The class can also be used without a physical LCD screen if LcdCanvas.target_LCD == None.  
    """


    class Card(object):
        """
        A card is an image that is positioned on the canvas. The coordinates of it
        are the upper left corner's of the image, and defaults to (0, 0).
        """


        def __init__(self, image, priority=0):
            """
            :param image: the Image to be used as the card
            :param priority: the priority of the card, higher overlaps lower
            """
            self.image = None
            self.size = 0
            self.change_image(image)
            self.position = (0, 0)
            self.priority = priority
            self.visible = True


        def change_image(self, image):
            """
            changes the card's picture with the conversion if neccessary
            :param image: the new image of the card
            """
            self.image = image
            if self.image.mode != '1':
                self.image = self.image.convert(mode='1', dither=Image.NONE)
            self.size = self.image.size


        def invert(self):
            """inverts the image (useful for i.e. highlighting)"""

            self.image = ImageChops.invert(self.image)


        def shift(self, amount):
            """
            moves the card by the given relative coordinates
            :param amount: the horizontal and vertical amount of shifting in pixels, tuple
            """
            x = amount[0] + self.position[0]
            y = amount[1] + self.position[1]
            self.position = (x, y)


        def align(self, horizontal, vertical):
            """
            Moves the card to the given position of the screen.
            :param horizontal: horizontal alignment; "left", "center", "right", or None
            :param vertical: vertical alignment; "top", "center", "bottom", or None
            """
            x, y = self.position[0], self.position[1]

            if horizontal == 'left':
                x = 0
            elif horizontal == 'center':
                x = int((LCD_WIDTH - self.size[0])/2)
            elif horizontal == 'right':
                x = LCD_WIDTH - self.size[0]

            if vertical == 'top':
                y = 0
            elif vertical == 'center':
                y = int((LCD_HEIGHT - self.size[1])/2)
            elif vertical == 'bottom':
                y = LCD_WIDTH - self.size[1]

            self.position = (x, y)


    class Textbox(object):
        """A special type of card that consist of a text and a frame. Size is auto-managed."""

        def __init__(self, text, text_color=0, font=None, spacing=0, text_align='left', frame_width=0, priority=0):
            """
            :param text: the text of the card
            :param text_color: the color of the text, 0 for black on white, else white on black
            :param font: the font type of the text (ImageFont instance)
            :param spacing: spacing between the lines of the text
            :param text_align: align of the text within the box ('left', 'center' or 'right')
            :param frame_width: the width of the frame line in pixels
            :param priority: higher overlaps lower
            """
            self.position = (0, 0)
            self.priority = priority
            self.visible = True

            self.text = None
            self.text_color = None
            self.font = None
            self.spacing = None
            self.text_align = None
            self.frame_width = None
            self.size = None
            self.image = Image.new('1', (0,0))  # dummy Image for ImageDraw
            self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

            self.edit_propertities(text, text_color, font, spacing, text_align, frame_width)


        def edit_propertities(self, text=None, text_color=None, font=0, spacing=None, text_align=None, frame_width=None):
            """
            Changes the card's given propertities (the ones that implies redrawing it)
            :param text: the text of the card
            :param text_color: the color of the text, 0 for black on white, else white on black
            :param font: the font type of the text (ImageFont instance)
            :param spacing: spacing between the lines of the text
            :param text_align: align of the text ('left', 'center' or 'right')
            :param frame_width: the width of the frame line in pixels
            """
            if text is not None:
                self.text = text
            if text_color is not None:
                self.text_color = 0 if text_color==0 else 255
            if font != 0:
                self.font = font
            if spacing is not None:
                self.spacing = spacing
            if text_align is not None:
                self.text_align = text_align
            if frame_width is not None:
                self.frame_width = frame_width

            x = self.draw.textsize(text)[0] + 2 + 2 * self.frame_width
            y = self.draw.textsize(text)[1] + 2 + 2 * self.frame_width
            self.size = (x, y)
            self.image = Image.new('1', self.size, (255 if self.text_color==0 else 0))
            self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

            text_coords = (self.frame_width + 1, self.frame_width + 1)
            #drawing text:
            self.draw.multiline_text(text_coords, self.text, fill=self.text_color, font=self.font,
                                     spacing=self.spacing, align=self.text_align)
            #drawing frame:
            for i in range(self.frame_width):
                self.draw.line([(i, 0), (i, self.size[1])], fill=self.text_color)  #left
                self.draw.line([(0, i), (self.size[0], i)], fill=self.text_color)  #top
                self.draw.line([(self.size[0]-1-i, 0), (self.size[0]-1-i, self.size[1])], fill=self.text_color)  #right
                self.draw.line([(0, self.size[1]-1-i), (self.size[0]), self.size[1]-1-i], fill=self.text_color)  #bottom



        def invert(self):
            """Inverts the image (useful for i.e. highlighting)."""

            self.image = ImageChops.invert(self.image)


        def shift(self, amount):
            """
            Moves the card by the given relative coordinates.
            :param amount: the horizontal and vertical amount of shifting in pixels, tuple
            """
            x = amount[0] + self.position[0]
            y = amount[1] + self.position[1]
            self.position = (x, y)


        def align(self, horizontal=None, vertical=None):
            """
            Moves the card to the given position; set None to do not change. 
            :param horizontal: horizontal alignment ('left', 'center', 'right' or None)
            :param vertical: vertical alignment ('top', 'center', 'bottom' or None)
            """
            x, y = self.position[0], self.position[1]
            if horizontal == 'left':
                x = 0
            elif horizontal == 'center':
                x = int((LCD_WIDTH - self.size[0])/2.0)
            elif horizontal == 'right':
                x = LCD_WIDTH - self.size[0]

            if vertical == 'top':
                y = 0
            elif vertical == 'center':
                y = int((LCD_HEIGHT - self.size[1])/2.0)
            elif vertical == 'bottom':
                y = LCD_WIDTH - self.size[0]

            self.position = (x, y)


    def __init__(self, target, base_color=1, base=None):
        """
        :param target: the LCD instance of the target Nokia 5110 LCD screen (use None for debug without an LCD)
        :param base_color: 0 for black, else white (if base == None)
        :param base: the base image on what the cards are drawn
        """
        self.LCD = target
        if self.LCD is not None:
            self.LCD.clear()
        if base is not None:
            self.base = base
            if self.base.size != (LCD_WIDTH, LCD_HEIGHT):
                self.base = self.base.resize((LCD_WIDTH, LCD_HEIGHT))
            if self.base.mode != '1':
                self.base = self.base.convert(mode='1', dither=Image.NONE)
        else:
            self.base = Image.new('1', (LCD_WIDTH, LCD_HEIGHT), (0 if base_color==0 else 255))

        #dictionary of all the image cards and textboxes. Keys are
        #the card_IDs, and the vaules are the cards themselves.
        self._cards = {}


    def add_card(self, card_ID, image, priority=0):
        """
        Adds a new card to the canvas.
        :param card_ID: the name of the card, should be unique
        :param image: the image of the card
        :param position: the position of the card ('s upper left corner)
        :param priority: the card with higher priority is drawn above the one with lower priority
        """
        if card_ID in self._cards.keys():
            raise ValueError("ID already exists")

        card = self.Card(image, priority)
        self._cards[card_ID] = card


    def add_textbox(self, card_ID,  text, text_color=0, font=None, spacing=0, align='left', frame_width=0, priority=0):
        """
        Adds a new textbox to the cards with the given propertities.
        :param card_ID: the name of the card, should be unique
        :param text: the text of the card
        :param text_color: the color of the text, 0 for black on white, else white on black
        :param font: the font type of the text (ImageFont instance)
        :param spacing: spacing between the lines of the text
        :param text_align: align of the text ('left', 'center' or 'right')
        :param frame_width: the width of the frame line in pixels
        :param priority: the card with higher priority is drawn above the one with lower priority
        """        
        if card_ID in self._cards.keys():
            raise ValueError("ID already exists")
        textbox = self.Textbox(text, text_color, font, spacing, align, frame_width, priority)
        self._cards[card_ID] = textbox


    def get_card(self, card_ID):
        """Returns the card itself, useful for reading their propertities."""

        return self._cards[card_ID]


    def edit_card_image(self, card_ID, image):
        """Changes the card's image"""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].change_image(image)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise TypeError("edit_card_image used on a Textbox", e)


    def edit_textbox(self, card_ID, text=None, text_color=None, font=0, spacing=None, align=None, frame_width=None):
        """Edits the textbox card's propertities. None means no change."""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].edit_propertities(text, text_color, font, spacing, align, frame_width)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")
        except AttributeError as e:
            raise TypeError("edit_textbox called on a non-Textbox card", e)


    def set_priority(self, card_ID, value):
        """Sets the card's priority"""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].priority = value    
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")


    def hide_card(self, card_ID):
        """Makes the card hidden."""

        self._cards[card_ID].visible = False


    def show_card(self, card_ID):
        """Makes the card visible."""

        self._cards[card_ID].visible = True


    def set_pos(self, card_ID, pos):
        """sets the card's position."""

        assert type(pos) is tuple
        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].position = pos
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")


    def shift(self, card_ID, amount):
        """Moves the card by the given amount of pixels.
            :param amount: the horizontal and vertical amount of shifting in pixels; tuple"""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].shift(amount)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")


    def align(self, card_ID, horizontal, vertical):
        """Aligns the card to the given position."""

        try:
            card = self._cards[card_ID]
            card.align(horizontal, vertical)
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID") 


    def invert(self, card_ID):
        """Inverts the card's colour"""

        try:
            self._cards[card_ID].invert()
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")


    def delete_card(self, card_ID):
        """Deletes the card."""

        try:
            del self._cards[card_ID]
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Invaild card ID")



    def construct_screen(self):
        """Flattens the canvas."""

        screen = self.base.copy()
        sorted_cards = sorted(self._cards.values(), key=lambda x: x.priority)   # sort the cards according to their priorities
        for card in sorted_cards:
            screen.paste(card.image, card.position)
        screen = screen.convert(mode='1', dither=Image.NONE)

        return screen


    def update_screen(self):
        """If self.LCD is specified, this outputs the canvas to it."""

        screen = self.construct_screen()
        if self.LCD is not None:
            self.LCD.image(screen)
            self.LCD.display()


    def debug_show_screen(self):
        """Outputs the canvas to the monitor instead of the LCD."""
        # note that normally the code is runned as root, and Image.show() does not work this way!
        self.construct_screen().show()





def main():
    """
    A test code that uses almost all functions of the libary. Outputs to the LCD screen (normal usage).
    """

    # pins of the Nokia LCD are connected to these GPIO pins
    LCD_BL = 22
    LCD_DC = 17
    LCD_RST = 27
    LCD_SPI_PORT = 0
    SPI_DEVICE = 0

    #lcd=None
    lcd = LCD.PCD8544(LCD_DC, LCD_RST, spi=SPI.SpiDev(LCD_SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=4000000))
    base = Image.new('RGB', (100,100), (200,0,0))
    canvas = LcdCanvas(lcd, base)

    square = Image.new('RGB', (10, 10), (0, 0, 0))
    canvas.add_card('square', square, 5)
    canvas.add_textbox('hodor', "Hodor\nhodor hodor\nhodor.", align='center', frame_width=1, priority=10)
    canvas.add_textbox('valmorg', "Valar\nMorghulis", align='right', frame_width=3, priority=1000)
    canvas.update_screen()
    print(1)
    time.sleep(2)

    canvas.align('valmorg', 'center', 'center')
    canvas.align('hodor', 'right', 'bottom')
    canvas.update_screen()
    print(2)
    time.sleep(2)

    canvas.invert('valmorg')
    canvas.update_screen()
    print(3)
    time.sleep(2)

    canvas.set_pos('hodor', (10, 10))
    canvas.shift('valmorg', (-5, 20))
    canvas.update_screen()
    print(4)
    time.sleep(2)

    rectangle = Image.new('HSV', (10, 20), (10, 20, 30))
    canvas.edit_card_image('square', rectangle)
    canvas.edit_textbox('hodor', text=".rodoh\nrodoh rodoh\nrodoH", spacing=2, align='left', frame_width=0)
    canvas.set_priority('valmorg', 0)
    canvas.update_screen()
    print(5)
    time.sleep(2)

    canvas.remove_card('valmorg')
    canvas.update_screen()


def debug_main():
    """
    A test code identical to main(), but outputs to the monitor, thus does not depend on the LCD libaries.
    """
    lcd = None
    base = Image.new('RGB', (100,100), (200,0,0))
    canvas = LcdCanvas(lcd, base)

    square = Image.new('RGB', (10, 10), (0, 0, 0))
    canvas.add_card('square', square, priority=5)
    canvas.add_textbox('hodor', "Hodor\nhodor hodor\nhodor.", align='center', frame_width=1, priority=1)
    canvas.add_textbox('valmorg', "Valar\nMorghulis", align='right', frame_width=3, priority=10)
    canvas.debug_show_screen()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    canvas.align('valmorg', 'center', 'center')
    canvas.align('hodor', 'right', 'bottom')
    canvas.debug_show_screen()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    canvas.invert('valmorg')
    canvas.debug_show_screen()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    canvas.set_pos('hodor', (10, 10))
    canvas.shift('valmorg', (-5, 20))
    canvas.debug_show_screen()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    rectangle = Image.new('HSV', (10, 20), (10, 20, 30))
    canvas.edit_card_image('square', rectangle)
    canvas.edit_textbox('hodor', text=".rodoh\nrodoh rodoh\nrodoH", align='left', frame_width=0)
    canvas.set_priority('valmorg', 0)
    canvas.debug_show_screen()
    time.sleep(0.5)

    canvas.delete_card('valmorg')
    canvas.debug_show_screen()


if __name__=='__main__':

    debug_main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Test code shouldn't be part of production code. It should be straightforward to convert `main` and `debug_main` to something compatible with `nosetests`. This has several advantages:

- Integration with xUnit frameworks
- Integration with code coverage tools
- One-word test script: `nosetests`

The only tests are in `main` and `debug_main`, which are acceptance or journey tests. This means your test pyramid completely missing several levels.

Running `pep8` on the code would reveal some stylistic issues. Whether you agree to them is one thing, but Python users in general will for example expect local variable and parameter names to be all lower case, even if they contain abbreviations.

Your shebang line will not be Python 3 on many common platforms. Personally I'd recommend using a service like Travis CI to run your tests with all versions of Python you intend to support, and to support at least the latest 2.x and 3.x versions. I've created an example [Python skeleton project](https://github.com/l0b0/python-skeleton) just for this use case.

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't test 'as is' - I don't have the experience for this at all -, only checked that the code indeed works. If I will ever sumbit the code, the debug functions will not be a part of it (maybe only as an example of usage). Anyway, I will surely check out the tools you mentioned.